# How to install different types of composer packages in different directories?

Tags: php, composer-php

I know that you can change the vendor directory by using

```
    "config": {
        "vendor-dir": "customdir"
    }
```

But this changes the directory for all packages. How can I change the directory for custom composer types?

Comment: why? what are you trying to accomplish with that?

Comment: I created a custom composer type (for my plugins) that I want to install in another directory (/plugins) than the 'normal' composer packages

Comment: Why? What's wrong with the package manager working normally, what benefit do you get if your package is in a different directory? Why go through trouble if you gain literally nothing?

Comment: Because my system will look in the /plugins folder to find plugins. Don't want to mix this with other external libraries as then I would need to look at all the composer packages and determine which one are plugins for my framework. This will slow down the framework.

Comment: You might be better of to use namespacing for your plugins. But have a look at https://getcomposer.org/doc/faqs/how-do-i-install-a-package-to-a-custom-path-for-my-framework.md for usage details for ```{ "extra": { "installer-paths": { "plugins/{$vendor}/{$name}" : [ "vendor:*" ] } } }```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this composer package: [Composer Custom Type Installer](https://github.com/davidbarratt/custom-installer).
Any custom type can be used to define a path the type should be installed in.

Got this example from the github about how to use it:

```
{
    "extra": {
        "custom-installer": {
            "web/": ["type:drupal-core"],
            "web/sites/{$name}/": ["type:drupal-site"],
            "custom/{$type}/{$vendor}/{$name}/": ["type:random-type"],
            "vendor/{$vendor}/{$name}/": ["type:library"],
            "web/sites/all/libraries/{$name}/": [
                "type:component",
                "ckeditor/ckeditor",
                "flesler/jquery.scrollto"
            ],
            "custom-folder-for-single-package": ["myvendorname/single-package"],
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like a great package! Will definitely check it out :)